# Change UIButton property on static func closure

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have **static API function** which is **void** and call external API, now I want to check the response and when it is **nil** I want to disable the button and change its color. 
But in Alamofire I can't access the button properties even with self.

```
@IBOutlet weak var AudioButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  // self.AudioButton.tintColor=UIColor.gray work here 
       if(gameData?.WordId != nil){

    APIClient.getWordAudio(id: gameData!.WordId)
                .execute(onSuccess: { response in
                    DatabaseManager.shared.saveWordAudios([response])//
                  let audioData = NSData(base64Encoded: response.content!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
                    // here I want to check for nil and then disable the button
 if(response.content==nil){
// this two line dosen't work inside this closure
                     self.AudioButton.tintColor=UIColor.gray                    
                    self.AudioButton.isEnabled=false;
                    }

              }, onFailure: { error in
                  print("[WordViewController] \(error)")

              }
                  )


        }

}
```

Comment: please show the declaration of AudioButton

Comment: it's a simple outlet
@IBOutlet weak var AudioButton: UIButton!

Comment: yes, value isn't important now 
I try it but no luck.

Comment: Check for the brackets.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad try changing tintColor to BackgroundColor. (I have just tried it on sample project didn't work with tintColor but works with backgroundColor) also isEnable Works correctly.

Comment: @chirag90 tried it but no luck. but I can change a label color on closure

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad Your problem is compile error or something else? What is error log

Comment: @ThanhVu there is no compile error

Answer (score 0):

Please show the declaration of AudioButton. I think you're accessing the class `AudioButton` instead of its object.

```
let audioButton: AudioButton?
```

then access the object from inside closure.

```
if(response.content==nil){
    self.audioButton.tintColor=UIColor.gray                    
    self.audioButton.isEnabled=false;
}
```

Comment: no please see Button declaration on the question.
Use of undeclared type 'AudioButton'

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and is working fine:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var AudioButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.AudioButton.tintColor=UIColor.red

    Alamofire.request("https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseData { (responseData) -> Void in
        if(responseData.data != nil) {
            self.AudioButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            self.AudioButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

[image: Label Color]

I tested with `Alamofire 4.0.0` and `5.0.0-beta.5`

Answer (score -1):

Set AudioButton as Strong variable, I think it will work.

`@IBOutlet var AudioButton: UIButton!`